# Why does reboot require sudo but shutdown does not?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, sudo, shutdown, reboot

I use Ubuntu 16.04. and 18.04. LTS and I was wondering why I have to be sudo to reboot (i.e. `sudo reboot`) but that the shutdown command does not require sudo. I can use any of its variants like `shutdown now` or `shutdown 3:00` without having to use sudo, even `shutdown now -r`, which in fact does reboot the system. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: well, I have to use sudo with shutdown on my computers.

Comment: In 16.10 you don't need sudo for either command. I don't know when they changed that.

Comment: I believe the change occurred after 15.04, with switch to systemd. As for reboot command itself, it might be separated from systemd, hence requires sudo. I'm not 100% sure on that, though

Comment: Clarification (after seeing the other comments): I need sudo for both reboot and shutdown on servers or an SSH session to a desktop. But both work without sudo on a gui terminal window on a desktop.